# Inputting char values into specific 2-d array elements C++, run-time check failure #2

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am quite new to programming, and am trying to write a simple tic-tac-toe type game, with one human player (me) and one computer player.

I am currently writing a piece of the program as a void function that allows the human player to input 'X' into the specified array component. I'm using a character array of size [2][2] as my game board, and want the player to enter two numbers, e.g. 1 & 2, to specify their next move.

The following code is what I am using to create the 3x3 game board, and initialize each array component to '_'. Please ignore the aiMove function prototype, as I have not written anything for it yet.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void playerMove(char[2][2]);
void aiMove(char[2][2]);

int col, row;

int main()
{

char ticTacToe[2][2];

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
    {
        ticTacToe[i][j] = '_'; //initializes all values of ticTacToe to '_'
        cout << (ticTacToe[i][j]); outputs the starting board
    }
    cout << endl; // ends line after iterating through each row, creating a 3x3 board appearance
}

playerMove(ticTacToe);

return 0;
}
```

Below is the code where I am having the problem. I create the void function playerMove, and pass the ticTacToe array to the playerBoard array. I ask the player to pick two numbers, and input those into col and row, respectively. Using the do...while loop, I ensure that they player can only enter 0, 1 and 2 for the values of col and row. I then use the values of col and row to input an 'X' into the [col][row] element of the array.

Now that part works, as in I can get an X to go where I want it to go. However, after inputting one value, the program crashes with the debug error message: 
Run-time check failure #2 - S.

I've done some research, and I think I know what is happening. By using the values of col and row to place the 'X' into the [col][row] element, I am inadvertently creating a situation where the playerBoard array could possibly go out of bounds. This is why I created the variables c and r, to see if by passing the values of col and row to these variables, I could effectively separate playerBoard from col and row. This didn't work.

So my two main questions are: 
1) Am I understanding the error message correctly, e.g. does the problem lie with using col and row to place an 'X' into that array element, or is there something else I am missing?

2) How do I fix this error/re-write the code so it doesn't happen? I need the player to be able to select a particular array element where the column value is 0-2 and the row value is 0-2, while also inputting an 'X' into this array element.

I hope my questions are clear! This is my first post on Stack Overflow, and I tried very hard to follow guidelines and write a clear question, so please go easy!

```
void playerMove(char playerBoard[2][2])
{
char move = 'X';
int c = 0, r = 0;

do
{
    cout << "Enter 2 numbers, 0-2, separated by a space. " << endl
        << "The first number is the column you wish to place your move " << endl
        << "and the second number is the row you wish to place your move. " << endl;
    cin >> col >> row;
} while (((col >= 0 && col <= 2) && (row >= 0 && row <= 2)) == false);

c = col;
r = row;

playerBoard[c][r] = move;

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
    {
        cout << playerBoard[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `<= 2` goes out of bounds, replace that with `< 2`.

Comment: If you are trying to create a 3x3 array, it should be declared array[3][3], not array [2][2]. The indices run 0 to 2.

Comment: Thank you  πάντα ῥεῖ  and paisanco, those two tips fixed the main problem I was having, plus a secondary problem. Such a simple fix... :)

Comment: So is the last element of the array, e.g. the 4th element, just a place-holder? and array of [3] has 4 elements, correct? (0, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: @Seth No. indices run from 0 -> (size - 1). there is no forth element.